# How to mount a loop device in android

Tags: android, linux, loops, mount

I have an linux img file I want to mount it to /data/local/mnt

The issue is when I use

su

losetup /dev/block/loop7 /sdcard/linux.img

mount -t ext4 /data/local/mnt /dev/block/loop7

it gives error !!
invalid argument !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution !!
I was actually writing in a wrong syntax
It should have been 
mount -t ext4 /dev/block/loop7 /data/local/mnt

Comment: You can accept your answer as an "answer" thus you can earn points :)